# window.open() is not working in desktop application

Tags: javascript, windows, reactjs, browser, electron

I am trying to open a new window using `window.open()`.
I have used `reactDOM.createPortal` to keep the controls of window in sync with parent component.

Here's a snippet:

```
export default class NewWindow extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerEl = document.createElement('div'); 
    this.externalWindow = null;
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=400,left=200,top=200');
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);

}
render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        this.props.children, this.containerEl);
}
}

class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent{
render(){
    return(
        <NewWindow>
            <div>Custom Text</div>
        </NewWindow>
    );
}
}
```

**Note** : I kept url part empty as i am trying to append a React component to it.

This is working fine in web-browser with about:blank as URL, but it is not working in desktop application.

Can any one help how can I open a new window and render a specific component in it inside desktop application?

Also let me know in case any alternate can be used.

Thanks in advance.

**PS** : Windows application is developed using React/Redux and Electron.

**Update** : When I provide a valid url, a new window opens but the base window goes blank.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know but somehow it seems odd that opening a browser window would translate to opening an application window.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It is working if I provide a url to window.open(). But is seems to have some issue when I send the URL part as empty string inside window.open()

Comment: I stand corrected. What about passing `"about:blank"`?

Comment: No It still is not working after providing `"about:blank"` as the url.

Comment: Portal don't work across windows AFAIK

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, It does work across the windows.
Here's [example] (https://codepen.io/davidgilbertson/pen/xPVMqp)

Comment: @Mahipal Did you fixed this issue.?

Comment: @mkHun I dug more into and got to know that due to security concerns, multiple windows with different url's were disabled in my application.